# Whats the best way to update or replace a hyperledger fabrc identity's

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, identity

Upon receiving the error below (see screenshot), I am trying to update or replace the certificate.
[image: Error returned after submitting API call]

Comment: Unclear exactly what you are doing here?  Which SDK are you using?  What does your client code look like?  What have you tried?

Comment: We built an API about 1 year ago and has been working well. All of a sudden we get that 500 error? No changes to the code? I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Fabric uses X509 certificates for it's identity management. X509 certificates have an expiry date. The ones you have used for your client application identity (and probably throughout your fabric setup as well) have an expiry date 1 year after creation. So your identity has expired and can't be used.

As for fixing the problem you are in a world of pain now for letting them expire especially as it looks like you built your application using hyperledger composer which you should have migrated off from ages ago which adds additional understanding because composer stores certificates within it's own metadata runtime (ie the participants)

I would suggest you redevelop your application using the latest hyperledger fabric release and utilise the latest client and chaincode node sdks. If your data is important then you could try to extract it from couchdb and then re-import it into your new application

As part of your re-development you need to fully understand the use of X509 certificates within hyperledger fabric, know what expiry date you plan to use when you generate them and be have a process in place to be able to renew them all before they expire.